# Singleton pattern in multi-threading may have duplication code

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, code-duplication, code-cleanup

I saw there is a tutorial online for Singleton, in order to implement multi-threading and ensure the instance only be instantiate once. The tutorial has code below, but in the code, then there is duplication code, as they want to make sure the instance is not null.

```
if(instance == null){}
```

However, this condition check show up twice, is this duplication ?

```
    public class Singleton {
        private static Singleton instance;


        private Singleton(){
            //Here runs a lot code, that's why we don't want to instantiate here
        }

        // Using synchronized to ensure Singleton (only instantiate once) when 
        //implement multi threading.
        public static Singleton getInstance(){
            if(instance == null){
                synchronized(Singleton.class){
                    if(instance == null){
                        instance = new Singleton();
                    }    
                }
            } 
            return instance;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's called [double checked locking](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton-double-checked-locking) for a reason.

Comment: to ensure no multithreading breaks the singleton pattern, add an `object` to your class and `lock` it just before checking null

Comment: @nalka the OP is not asking about object locking.  they are asking why `instance` is checked twice.  please do not add irrelevant information, as it will just confuse the OP.

Comment: It is fact checked twice, but there is a good reason to, in that specific case, check twice. Check @bommelding link (it is java, but the concept is the same) or my answer, where I try to explain why the second `if` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not duplicated. It is checked again because between the first check `if(instance == null)` and the locking `synchronized(Singleton.class)` another thread could instantiate it and break the singleton. Check the differences between the first code block and the second one.

```
    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            // Another thread could instantiate in this moment.
            synchronized(Singleton.class){
                instance = new Singleton(); // If another thread did already instantiate it, this would be the second call to the constructor.
            }
        } 
        return instance;
    }
```

Checking again after the lock has been done prevents that race condition.

```
    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            // Another thread could instantiate in this moment.
            synchronized(Singleton.class){
                // Now this code is thread safe
                if(instance == null){
                    // No other thread made a race condition before the first check and the locking. We can safely do the heavy work.
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }    
            }
        } 
        return instance;
    }
```